# How to prove this Boolean expression?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following Boolean expression:

A'B'C + A'BC' + A'BC + AB'C' + AB'C + ABC' + ABC = A + B + C

I have tried using the distributive law and trying to cancel out some of the letters, and I keep getting something along the lines of A'B + C. I'm not sure how to start this problem, because trying to take out a common factor and trying to cancel doesn't seem to workout for me. I basically need to show the steps on how it equals A + B + C.

Any suggestions? I've been stuck at this for a while.

Also a note, I haven't learned K-maps yet or any super advanced techniques yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main laws used here are $x+x'=1$ and $x+x'y=x+y$. If you haven't learned them yet, they can be easily verified with a truth table.

\begin{align*}
&A'B'C + A'BC' + A'BC + AB'C' + AB'C + ABC' + ABC\\
&=A'(B'C+BC'+BC)+A(B'C'+B'C+BC'+BC)\\
&=A'(B'C+B(C'+C))+A(B'(C'+C)+B(C'+C))\\
&=A'(B'C+B)+A(B'+B)\\
&=A'(B'C+B)+A\\
&=A'(B+C)+A\\
&=A+B+C
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh! I completely messed up and thought (B'C + B) was just C.... now I see where I messed up. Thank you!!